# Upgrade to debian buster, users can't mount USB storage in XFCE

Tags: debian, usb

Upgraded a bunch of Debian machine from stretch to buster. Those machines are running XFCE and are part of a NIS domain.
On a few of them, users can't mount USB storage anymore from XFCE after upgrade while it was working fine under stretch.

USBdisk icon displayed on the desktop but when double click on it -> Failed to mount "keyName" Not authorized to perform operation

```
==> syslog <==
Oct 17 07:34:11 machine kernel: [  184.011692] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1666, bcdDevice= 1.10
Oct 17 07:34:11 machine kernel: [  184.011696] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Oct 17 07:34:11 machine kernel: [  184.011698] usb 3-2: Product: DataTraveler 3.0
Oct 17 07:34:11 machine kernel: [  184.011700] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Kingston
Oct 17 07:34:11 machine kernel: [  184.011701] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 408D5C1653D4E2A1B98AA273
Oct 17 07:34:11 machine mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 2: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2"
Oct 17 07:34:11 machine mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 2 was not an MTP device
Oct 17 07:34:11 machine kernel: [  184.039916] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Oct 17 07:34:11 machine kernel: [  184.040232] scsi host10: usb-storage 3-2:1.0
Oct 17 07:34:11 machine kernel: [  184.040336] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Oct 17 07:34:11 machine kernel: [  184.043119] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
Oct 17 07:34:11 machine mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 2: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2"
Oct 17 07:34:11 machine mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 2 was not an MTP device
Oct 17 07:34:12 machine kernel: [  185.059788] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DataTraveler 3.0 PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Oct 17 07:34:12 machine kernel: [  185.060205] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
Oct 17 07:34:12 machine kernel: [  185.060459] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] 60604416 512-byte logical blocks: (31.0 GB/28.9 GiB)
Oct 17 07:34:12 machine kernel: [  185.060766] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
Oct 17 07:34:12 machine kernel: [  185.060768] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 45 00 00 00
Oct 17 07:34:12 machine kernel: [  185.061076] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Oct 17 07:34:12 machine kernel: [  185.082929]  sdc: sdc1
Oct 17 07:34:12 machine kernel: [  185.084849] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

- There is no udev or polkit rules on the machines.
- I did a comparison of installed packages using dpkg -l between 2 machines (one working fine, the other one not), except for a few java dev packages, there is no differences
- When logged in as root, I can mount usb storage without problem
- I did a file comparison of /etc/ between 2 machines using rsync -anvc, did not find any big things in there
- tried to apt install --reinstall thunar, thunar-volman and related gvfs packages
- Upgraded bios/fw of motherboard

After reading a few old posts about that on the web, we launched thunar from terminal using "dbus-launch thunar" and we got this error.

```
thunar-volman: Unsupported USB device type "usb". thunar-volman:
Unsupported USB device type "usb-storage". thunar-volman: Unknown
block device type "disk".
```

Else, nothing in syslog/messages.

Answer (score -1):

it works for me.

1) Add this line in  /etc/pam.d/common-session

session optional        pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=077
like written at this page

https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Debian_10&p=nis&f=2

2) start nscd service

3) reboot your machine

Comment: This is for the home folder creation isn't it? But those folders already exists.